# How to prevent onDataChange() run multiple time in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an app which creates an FCM token when application runs for the first time then the token is saved in firebase database against a mobile number.

The procedure of saving data in database is to first retrieve the data from database and then in `onDataChange()` it should update the data if it already exits otherwise data is new created.

Now the problem is this: When I open the app the using a mobile number '1234' and in database token against this is lets say '1' . Now if i open the app in another mobile using same number i.e, '1234' , the token in other device is let's say '2'. In database the token against number 1234 should update from '1' to '2' but it is not happening . In fact, when the data updates to 2 then again it converted to 1 then again 2 then 1 then again 2 and so on.

I want if a new token is generated against a mobile number then it should be updated.

This is my code:

```
tokenZ = new Token();
SharedPreferences sharedPreferenceZ =activity.getSharedPreferences(cmn.SHARED_SPNAME,MODE_PRIVATE);
final String tokens = sharedPreferenceZ.getString(cmn.RegistrationTokenforFirebase, "1");
final DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
final DatabaseReference databaseChild = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("" + UserID);

database.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Map<String, Object> oldData = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

        if (oldData != null) {
            System.out.println("oldDD" + oldData.get(UserID));
            System.out.println("oldDDy" + "{token=" + tokens + "}");

            if (oldData.get(UserID) != null) {
                System.out.println("Number already");


                Map<String, Object> currentData = (Map<String, Object>) oldData.get(UserID);

                if (oldData.get(UserID).toString().equals("{token=" + tokens + "}")) {
                    System.out.println("Token already");
                    currentData.put("token", tokens);
                    databaseChild.updateChildren(currentData);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("New Token");
                    //  databaseChild.removeValue();
                    tokenZ.setToken(tokens);
                    databaseChild.setValue(tokenZ);
                    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().setAutoInitEnabled(false);

                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("New Number");
                tokenZ.setToken(tokens);
                databaseChild.setValue(tokenZ);
            }
        } else {
            tokenZ.setToken(tokens);
            databaseChild.setValue(tokenZ);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to listen for the value in the database once, use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`.

So something like:

```
database.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  ...
```

---

You might want to consider allowing multiple FCM tokens in the database though, as the user can easily be active on multiple devices at/around the same time, and you may want to notify them on all to maximize the changes that they'll get the notification.

One way to manage all devices for a user is through an [FCM device group](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group).